what does it mean for a transformation of the sphere to be homeomorphic to a rotation?
I am reading the 1919 German article "Über die periodischen Transformationen der Kreisscheibe und der Kugelfläche", and encountering phrases like: "t als einer Spiegelung homöomorph erkaant ist." which Google translates as "t is recognized as homeomorphic to a reflection". What does it mean for a transformation (t) to be homeomorphic to a reflection? or homeomorphic to a rotation? Is it the same as being conjugate by a homeomorphism?
If you know a more modern expository reference for these facts about transformations of 2-spheres, that would also be appreciated.

Maybe it was meant to be "homotopic" or "isotopic". Check these notion out.

I'm guessing this means "up to a homeomorphism".

In this context, it means "conjugate by a homeomorphism."
